# KDB Excluding rows that have nulls

Tags: null, kdb

I have a table that has a handful of cells with null values (scattered across the dataset).  Any simple way of exluding all rows that have a null in any of its columns?

I'm just trying to avoid this...

```
select from T where not null col1, not null col2, not null col3, etc...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either use simple list functions for easy to read code 
or functional form for speed.
The functional form will be faster as it doesn't scan all the entire columns just those that pass each stage of the filter.

```
q)t:flip `a`b`c`d`e!flip {5?(x;0N)} each til 10
q)t
a b c d e
---------
0       0
  1   1
  2 2 2
3 3   3 3
4 4 4 4 4
      5 5
        6
7 7
  8     8
9 9   9 9

// simple way
q)where all each not null t
,4
q)t where all each not null t
a b c d e
---------
4 4 4 4 4

// faster
q)?[t;{(not;(null;x))} each cols t; 0b; ()]
a b c d e
---------
4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: In your functional form, what would be the code for returning the nulls instead?

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Ryan's answer.....if your table has string (nested) columns then you'll need to modify the functional form a little:

```
q)tab:([] col1:`a`b`c`d;col2:1 0N 3 0N;col3:"v vv";col4:0n 1.0 2.0 3.0;col5:("";"";"rf";"er"))

q)tab
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
------------------------
a    1    v         ""
b              1    ""
c    3    v    2    "rf"
d         v    3    "er"
```

Then using zero count as the indicator of a null string:

```
q)?[`tab;not,'enlist each @[(null;0=count');"C"=exec t from meta tab],'cols tab;0b;()]
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
------------------------
c    3    v    2    "rf"
```

Comment: EDIT - I was missing an "each"

Comment: t(&:)&/'[(~:)(^:)t]

Comment: or in k)t[&&/'~^t]

Comment: @egor7 accessing k operators in the q interpreter by wrapping with () is highly discouraged and definitely bad style. it certainly won't be understood by inexperienced users reading these comments. you should amend your first comment to `t where min each not null t`

Comment: furthermore this is equivalent to Ryan's `t where all each not null t` which, as he mentioned, is slower than the functional form