# Remove rows containing null values efficiently

Tags: null, kdb, q

What is the most efficient way to remove rows containing any null values, for a table with many rows?

Additionally, why do I get the error

`ERROR: 'time (attempt to use variable time without defining/assigning first`

even though I have nothing named as ‘time’ when using the functional select

`?[t;{(not;(null;x))} each cols t; 0b; ()]`

given in [this S/Oanswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865359/kdb-excluding-rows-that-have-nulls)?

Comment: That error doesn't look like a standard kdb error, it looks like error-trapping that someone has placed around your queries. Are you using an interface or IDE? Also, is your `t` table an in-memory table or an on-disk table?

Comment: I am using QPad and the table is in-memory

Comment: Ok. Can you show us the result of `(type t;meta t)`?

Comment: ```type t``` returns ```98h``` and ```meta t``` returns ```d,p,s,f,j,b```

Comment: Solved the unusual time error: I simply had a typo replacing one of the t’s in the functional select with another character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your table in memory or splayed on disk?

If your table is in memory, then a simple form might also be the fastest.

```
show t:flip`a`b`c`d`e!(1+til 100)*/:100 cut 500?(1 0N)where 19 1
a  b  c  d  e
--------------
1  1     1  1
2  2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4  4
5  5  5  5  5
6  6  6  6  6
7  7  7  7  7
8  8  8  8  8
9  9  9  9  9
10 10 10 10 10
11 11 11 11 11
12 12 12 12 12
13    13 13 13
14 14 14 14 14
15 15 15 15 15
16 16    16 16
   17 17 17 17
18 18 18 18 18
..

q)\ts:1000 ?[t;{(not;(null;x))}each cols t;0b;()]
5 7552
q)\ts:1000 t where not any null flip t
2 6768
```

If the table is splayed on disk, the game changes. In a splayed table each column is stored as a file. The second argument of the [Select](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/#select) operator is a list of constraints; each one a parse tree. Whereas `null flip t` above tests every cell of `t`, Select applies is constraints *successively*: only rows that have passed previous constraints are tested for the next. If no rows satisfy the first constraint/s subsequent column files may never need to be read at all.

From this follows the rule: list your constraints in descending order of restrictiveness – if nulls are more common in certain columns, test them first.

Regarding an in-memory test, note that `not any` can be a good deal faster than `all not`, depending on whether nulls are common.

```
q)q:null flip t
q)\ts:10000 all not q
9 1168
q)\ts:10000 not any q
6 656
```